# Starting from state 0, compute the mean number of visits of state 1 from one-step transition probability matrix.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

A Markov chain has one-step transition probability matrix
$$
        \mathrm P= \begin{pmatrix}
        1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\
        1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Starting from state 0, compute the mean number of visits of state 1.

First, I set up 3 equations.
$$m_0=1+\frac 14(m_0+m_1+m_2+m_3)$$
$$m_2=1+\frac 12(m_2+m_3)$$
$$m_3=1+\frac 13m_2+\frac 23m_3$$

Second, set $m_1=0$ then solve the above equations, I find the following one by gaussian elimination.

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        3 & -1 & -1 | 4 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 | 2 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 | -3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Am i wrong in some steps?

Comment: Is $m_k$ the mean number of visits to $1$ starting from state $k$?

Comment: I think so. Starting from the state $k$

Comment: Provided the state at time $0$ is among those counted, don't you have $m_0=(1/4)m_0+(1/4)m_1$ and $m_1=(1/4)m_0+(1/4)(1+m_1)$? (States 2 and 3 won't play a role in this problem.)

Comment: In the suggested solution above, it should be $m_{1} = 1+(1/4)m_{0}+(1/4)m_{1}$. (That is, the $1$ should not be multiplied by $1/4$.) Cheers.

Comment: That's correct -- Thanks, @Rubarb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\tau = \inf\{n>0: X_n\in\{2,3\}\}$$ the first passage time into $\{2,3\}$.
Let $Y$ be the number of visits to state $1$. Then for each $n>0$, $Y\mid \tau=n$ follows a $\operatorname{Bin}\left(n-1,\frac12\right)$ distribution. Since $\tau$ itself has $\operatorname{Geo}\left(\frac12\right)$ distribution, we compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y] &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb E\left[Y\mid \tau=n\right]\mathbb P(\tau = n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac12(n-1)\left(\frac12\right)^n\\
&= \frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)\left(\frac12\right)^n\\
&= \frac14\left(\frac1{\left(1-\frac12\right)^2} \right)\\
&= 1.
\end{align}